# Simple XML parsing with LINQ

Tags: c#, xml, linq, xml-parsing

I would like to parse this XML :

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="Windows-1252" ?>
<TEST>Login inexistant</TEST>
```

I wrote this code

```
var result  = from item in XElement.Parse(m_strRetour).Descendants("TEST")
              select item;
return result.First().ToString();
```

m_strRetour is a string that contains my XML.

After execution, result is empty.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`TEST` seems to be your root node, so it can't be a `Descendant`.

To get the value out of it you could try this.

```
var xml = "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='Windows-1252' ?><TEST>Login inexistant</TEST>";

var result  = XElement.Parse(xml);
var value = result.Value;
```

Answer (score 2):

`XElement.Parse` will return the `TEST` element itself - which doesn't have any descendants. (Also, there's *no* benefit in using a query expression here. Whenever you write `from x in y select x` you should consider whether you couldn't just use `y` instead...)

You could parse it as an `XDocument` instead, in which case there *would* be a `TEST` descendant... or you could just use the `XElement` itself.

What are you really trying to achieve though? Does your *real* XML only have a single element?